# Example of a symmetry and the group with which it is modelled?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, group-representations

Could you please provide a specific example of a symmetry and the group with which it is modelled? I am beginner to study symmetry in physics, please answer with just an example. This question is different from [How to model a symmetry using Lie Groups?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47275/2451), I need some simple example.

Comment: Symmetry in physics is a very broad topic, could you please specify a bit the level of the awnser you're looking for ? You should check out books on phase transitions at a graduate level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to model a symmetry using Lie Groups?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/47275/)

Comment: Saying "I need a simple explanation" doesn't actually make your question any different. How are we supposed to know what constitutes "simple" for you?

Comment: You might start with Wikipedia on Eugene Wigner, and go from there. But, 'symmetry' can mean different things in different parts of physics. For, say, crystallography the concept of symmetry is fairly straightforward.

Comment: What about rotational symmetry and the SO(3) group and the conservation of angular momentum, does it seem like a simple and good example ?

Comment: yes, thanks, could you give me some more example like that?

Comment: Hi @rahaa. List questions tend to fit poorly on Phys.SE. I'm closing this as a _duplicate,_ not because it is an exact duplicate, but to point in the right direction.